# SQL new stored procedure cannot be found when used in new query

Tags: sql

I recently created a procedure and I'm trying to make use of it in an existing procedure, but when I try to use it Intellisense will mark it as red underlined and say it is not found.  I check the database to ensure that the procedure exists and can find it in the list.  I read a few of the related questions about not finding a procedure, but it doesn't seem to matter what user is logged in to the database.

I did try this on another machine to see if I got similar results, but it could actually use the new procedure without issue.  Is there some reason Intellisense not picking up the procedure after it was created?  I'm used to working more in .NET languages where I can create a new object/type/method and make use of it almost immediately.  I just want to understand what to do when creating a new procedure so that I can make use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refresh Intellisense with ctrl+shift+R

The procedure is stored in system tables in SQL Server and Intellisense has to be told to read these tables to know what objects are available

That is, SQL Server Intellisense works differently to .net Intellisense that knows your objects and methods etc